# Password protect zip file with 7-zip that works between Android and Windows

Tags: applications, password, zip

Is there a way to password protect a zip file with 7-zip on a pc, then unzip the file on android (while requiring the password), and essentially use it on either pc or android?

I tried with es explorer, as well as fz explorer, and I'm not seeing any of the needed functionality. Any help/suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Never tried it but my first try would be [RAR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rarlab.rar) and [TotalCommander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghisler.android.TotalCommander)

Comment: This question is more suitable for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Handling archives isn't Android's built-in functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Try MixPlorer. I think it got what you need.